# Allow AWS Athena to query AWS access logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I store my nginx access logs in AWS S3, and I would like to use Athena to query these logs.

I can successfully create the database table, but when I try to query the logs in the Athena console, I get the following error:

```
Your query has the following error(s):
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: XXXXX; S3 Extended Request ID: XXXXXX=; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: XXXXXX= (Path: s3://your-alb-logs-directory/AWSLogs/XXXXXXXXX/elasticloadbalancing/eu-central-1)

This query ran against the "default" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: XXXXXXX
```

This is the query I am trying to run:

```
SELECT COUNT(request_verb) AS count,
         request_verb,
         client_ip
FROM alb_logs
GROUP BY  request_verb, client_ip LIMIT 100
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

The S3 bucket is stored on the same root account.

I tried to add the following policy to the Athena s3 query bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe the allowed action is not ok. What is the sdk operation you are trying to do? Take a look here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/udf-iam-access.html

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you allow ListBucket, PutObject and GetObject. Maybe you are trying another action like Query. I'm saying this not because I worked with Athena but worked with DynamoDB or RDS ant this was the main reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you allowed your ALB logs s3 bucket access form services?

I have a s3 resource policy on the ALB logs that includes

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
  {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AWSACCOUNT:root"
    },
    "Action": "s3:PutObject",
    "Resource": [
      "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/PATH/AWSLogs/AWSACCOUNT/*"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": "s3:PutObject",
    "Resource": [
      "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/PATH/AWSLogs/ACCOUNT_NUMBER/*"
    ],
    "Condition": {
      "StringEquals": {
        "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME"
  }
]
}
```